# How do I star an organization on GitHub?

Tags: github

I know how to star a repository but how can I star an organization so that I can keep track of all repositories in the organization?

For example, [this](https://github.com/WICG) organization has a lot of awesome repositories on web standards and I cannot just star all of them. I don't want to just bookmark the URLs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately GitHub doesn't offer the ability to follow an organization anymore.  There used to be a JavaScript workaround you could use, but that doesn't work anymore either.

There is currently [an open issue](https://github.com/isaacs/github/issues/50) regarding the ability to follow organizations -- you can add your voice to the already-long list, if you want.  It seems a lot of people would like to have that feature.

In the mean time, as a sort of workaround, you can follow [the seven people in that organization](https://github.com/orgs/WICG/people), and (while a bit cumbersome) you will get notifications when they modify or create repositories.

Comment: This is now tracked at https://github.com/github/feedback/discussions/4585

Comment: as per this [comment,](https://github.com/github/feedback/discussions/4585#discussioncomment-2412039) you can now follow organizations! 

Comment: docs at [Following an organization on GitHub](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/exploring-projects-on-github/following-organizations#following-an-organization-on-github)

Answer (score 0):

This feature is also what I want from GitHub. I've told them several years(? months) ago, but they didn't do that. (I think maybe they take it  too complex, but the one I want is just very simple) So I created a chrome extension: [Chrome extension here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/github-buddy-yeah-a-dog/obacpeecfhbgognjpnponfblnhpnepae), wish you are using chrome...